# why std::allocator::rebind doesn't cause recursion definition?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm confused in this piece code coming from GCC, why the other here doesn't cause recursion definition? It looks like related to meta-template programming, but I'm not sure.

```
//ext/alloc_traits.h
 206  template<typename _Tp>
 207  struct rebind
 208  { typedef typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Tp>::other other; };
```

it can be used, for example, list container

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc>
    class _List_base
    {
    protected:
      typedef typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::template rebind<_Tp>::other _Tp_alloc_type;
      typedef typename _Tp_alloc_traits::template rebind<_List_node<_Tp> >::other _Node_alloc_type;        
      //...
    };
```

So my question is why **typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Tp>::other** can be used to assign a type, whereas the other itself is becoming the new type.

Comment: Is (equivalent) `using other = typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Tp>::other;` clearer for you?

Comment: It isn't recursive because `_Alloc` is a different type than the one this is nested in.